# VBA Script Calculation of Specific Cells in CSV File

Tags: vba, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to determine the best method for producing a calculation of 3 values within a cell in my VBA script:

The script in it's current format:

```
Function BuildValuesString(colIndex As String, rows As String) As String
    Dim val As Variant

    For Each val In Split(rows, ",")
        If Cells(val, colIndex) <> "" Then BuildValuesString = BuildValuesString & Cells(val, colIndex).Value & ","
    Next val
End Function
Function BuildNullStrings(numNullStrings As Long) As String
    Dim iNullStrings As Long

    For iNullStrings = 1 To numNullStrings
        BuildNullStrings = BuildNullStrings & "" & ","
    Next iNullStrings
End Function


Sub WriteCSVFile2()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim logSTR As String

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    logSTR = logSTR & "Srv" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "E-mail" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Env." & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Protect" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "DB" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "# VMs" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Name" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Cluster" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "VLAN" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "NumCPU" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "MemoryGB" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "C" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "D" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "App" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "TotalDisk" & ","
    logSTR = logSTR & "Datastore" & ","

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33")

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44")

    logSTR = logSTR & Chr(13)

    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "18,19,20,21,22")
    logSTR = logSTR & BuildValuesString("C", "48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55")


Open "Z:\Requests(Test)\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

This VBA script is exporting the data from the Excel sheets cells into a CSV file and I would like to have it also calculate the numbers present in cell "C" "32" OR "C" "33" and be placed in the proceeding cell in the CSV file under the 'TotalDisk' header.

The values will be 3 numbers separated by a column; for example: 20, 30, 10. I would like the result of adding those 3 numbers (60, in the example) be placed in the next cell.

The reason for needing the calculation in C-32 **OR** C-33 is that data will only be filled in one or the other. As such, I will also need to do the same thing for cells C-43 OR C-44 and C-54 OR C-55.

Thank you for any information you may provide

Comment: Please give example input/arguments to this function, as well as **both** examples of *desired* output and *actual* output (and brief description of how these differ, or any specific error/problem you have with it)

Comment: @DavidZemens It would obviously be easier for me to create a calculated field within the Excel document that the VBScript is exporting to the CSV file - but even then, is it possible to do a calculation within a field in Excel based on values separated by a comma? The single cell would contain data: 20, 20, 10 and I have only seen calculations done based on values present in separate cells i.e. C4+C5+C6= result. Not sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'sum the comma-separated values in the first non-empty cell in rng
Function TotalIt(rng As Range)
    Dim c, arr, t, rv As Double, v
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(c.Value, ",")
            For Each v In arr
                If IsNumeric(v) Then rv = rv + v
            Next v
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    TotalIt = rv
End Function

'usage (add at the appropriate places in your code)
logSTR = logSTR & TotalIt(Range("C32:C33"))
```

BTW VBA has a built-in `String()` function which does the same thing as your `BuildNullStrings`

Comment: Thank you for the response - I am trying to use your provided solution but it doesn't appear to be placing the calculations anywhere in the CSV file. It doesn't return an error when I run it either. Is the TotalIt (Range) portion relate to the cell in the original Excel sheet that is being exported or the cells in the CSV file itself? The cells in the CSV that need to be calculated end up being L2, M2, N2 - would that be causing the lack of output? Thanks again for your help

Comment: I didn't give you the full solution, just the function and an example of how to call it from your main code.

Comment: Ah I see - I am very new with VBA and don't fully understand a lot of how it works and how functions are formatted. I apologize for the misunderstanding. What would I be missing from the code to have this be applied fully?

Comment: See above: just add that line to the relevant part of your code.  BTW are you sure your `BuildValuesString` is doing what you want?  If one of the input cells is empty it omits that field altogether (doesn't even write a comma) so the line line after that will shift one position to the left...

Comment: Yeah, I have that in there so I did not need to add additional header fields to handle that data should I have the other cell filled in. Those cells in particular are handling data that will pertain to one OS or another and the headers pertain to the disk size for one or the other. Thank you very much for the assistance with the code, the calculation worked perfectly and I have the desired result now. I was trying to add `tot = TotalIt (Range("C32:C33"))` to that section but was not having any luck - this clears everything up and I really appreciate your help